# Problem recording RTP from mediasoup router using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, sdp, mediasoup

I have a mediasoup server setup where I now need recording feature. To accomplish this I am doing the following -
On getting the event to start recording I call this function :

```js
async handleStartRecording(peer, router)
    {
        let transports = [],
            consumers = [],
            ffmpegInput = {};
        for(let entry of peer.producers.entries())
        {
            const rtpTransport = await router.createPlainTransport({
                comedia: false,
                rtcpMux: false,
                listenIp: { ip: '127.0.0.1', announcedIp: null }
            });
            transports.push(rtpTransport);

            const port = (entry[1].kind === 'audio') ? 8994 : 8996;
            const rtcpPort = port+1;

            await rtpTransport.connect({
                ip: '127.0.0.1',
                port: port,
                rtcpPort: rtcpPort,
                rtcpMux: false
            });
            peer.addTransport(rtpTransport.id, rtpTransport);

            const rtpConsumer = await rtpTransport.consume({
                producerId: entry[0],
                rtpCapabilities: router.rtpCapabilities, 
                paused: true,
            });
            consumers.push(rtpConsumer);

            const codecs = [];
            const routerCodec = router.rtpCapabilities.codecs.find(
              codec => codec.kind === entry[1].kind
            );
            codecs.push(routerCodec);
            const rtpCapabilities = {
                codecs,
                rtcpFeedback: []
            };

            ffmpegInput[entry[1].kind] = {
                port,
                rtcpPort,
                localRtcpPort: rtpTransport.rtcpTuple ? rtpTransport.rtcpTuple.localPort : undefined,
                rtpCapabilities,
                rtpParameters: rtpConsumer.rtpParameters,
                preferredPayloadType: routerCodec.payloadType
            };
        }
        
        ffmpegInput.fileName = Date.now().toString();
        peer._process = new FFmpeg(ffmpegInput, consumers);
    }
```

and the ffmpeg class is :

```js
class FFmpeg {
    constructor(rtpParameters, consumers) {
        this._rtpParameters = rtpParameters;
        this._consumers = consumers;
        this._process = undefined;
        this._createProcess();
    }
    _createProcess() {
        this._process = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', this._commandArgs);
        consumers.forEach((consumer) =>
        {
            consumer.resume();
        });
    }
get _commandArgs() {
        let commandArgs = [
            '-loglevel',
            'debug',
            '-protocol_whitelist',
            'file,crypto,pipe,udp,rtp',
            '-fflags',
            '+genpts',
            '-i',
            '/recording/input-h264.sdp', //path to sdp file has full path this is sample
            '-map',            // video
            '0:v:0',
            '-c:v',
            'copy',
            '-map',            //audio
            '0:a:0',
            '-strict',
            '-2',
            '-c:a',
            'copy',
            '-f',
            'webm',
            '-flags',
            '+global_header',
            '-y',
            `/files/${this._rtpParameters.fileName}.webm`
        ]);
        return commandArgs;
    }
}
```

Sdp file :

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=FFmpeg
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
m=video 8996 RTP/AVPF 101
a=rtcp:8997
a=rtpmap:101 VP8/90000
a=fmtp:101 level-asymmetry-allowed=1
m=audio 8994 RTP/AVPF 100
a=rtcp:8995
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
```

Now, I am getting a codec parameter not found for stream 0 error.

```sh
createProcess() [sdpString:v=0
            o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
            s=FFmpeg
            c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
            t=0 0
            m=video 8996 RTP/AVP 101
            a=rtpmap:101 VP8/90000
            a=sendonly
            m=audio 8994 RTP/AVP 100
            a=rtpmap:100 opus/48000/2
            a=sendonly
            ]
commandArgs:[ '-analyzeduration',
  '2147483647',
  '-probesize',
  '2147483647',
  '-loglevel',
  'debug',
  '-protocol_whitelist',
  'file,crypto,pipe,udp,rtp',
  '-fflags',
  '+genpts',
  '-i',
  '/recording/input-h264.sdp',
  '-map',
  '0:v:0',
  '-c:v',
  'copy',
  '-map',
  '0:a:0',
  '-strict',
  '-2',
  '-c:a',
  'copy',
  '-f',
  'webm',
  '-flags',
  '+global_header',
  '-y',
  '/files/1623939179824.webm',
  [length]: 28 ]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-analyzeduration' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as AVOption 'analyzeduration' with argument '2147483647'.
Reading option '-probesize' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '2147483647'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,crypto,pipe,udp,rtp'.
Reading option '-fflags' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+genpts'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '/recording/input-h264.sdp'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:v:0'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-map' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:a:0'.
Reading option '-strict' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
 matched as AVOption 'strict' with argument '-2'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'webm'.
Reading option '-flags' ...]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data: matched as AVOption 'flags' with argument '+global_header'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '/files/1623939179824.webm' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /recording/input-h264.sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /recording/input-h264.sdp.
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[NULL @ 0x55b7141c1a80] Opening '/recording/input-h264.sdp' for reading
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] video codec set to: vp8
[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] audio samplerate set to: 48000
[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] audio channels set to: 2
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[udp @ 0x55b7141c4d40] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x55b7141cac00] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] setting jitter buffer size to 500
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[udp @ 0x55b7141c5d40] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[udp @ 0x55b7141c5e00] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] setting jitter buffer size to 500
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 262 bytes read:262 seeks:0 nb_streams:2
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp8, 1 reference frame, yuv420p): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[sdp @ 0x55b7141c1a80] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 262 bytes read:262 seeks:0 frames:0
Input #0, sdp, from '/recording/input-h264.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : FFmpeg
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: vp8, 1 reference frame, yuv420p, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/48000: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url /files/1623939179824.webm.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:v:0.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:a:0.
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option f (force format) with argument webm.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /files/1623939179824.webm.
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[file @ 0x55b714243880] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:Successfully opened the file.
]
ffmpeg::process::data(err) [data:[webm @ 0x55b71423e100] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 0x55b714243b00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x55b7141cacc0] Statistics: 262 bytes read, 0 seeks
]
ffmpeg::process::close
```

I have been at it for days, I don't even know how to debug this issue. I tried using vlc's stream option with the url of server to check if the transport was working but it doesn't detect anything on localhost at that port.
If anyone has any ideas about the issue or ways to debug it, do tell me..

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't get ffmpeg to record from sdp input. So I finally resorted to using gstreamer to do it.
Example here : [mediasoup recording demo](https://github.com/Kurento/mediasoup-demos/tree/master/mediasoup-recording)

Comment: This is not the accepted answer unless you have found the solution for FFPMEG.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. The challenge is to find the proper ffmpeg command line and the right SDP. I could make it run based on your code. Thanks for sharing it